# Installing SSL Certificate

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate

I am trying to install an SSL certificate on my Apache server that's hosted on an EC2 instance from AWS. I originally intended to go with AWS Certificate Manager and put the SSL on a Load Balancer but I have no need for more than one EC2 instance. 
What I have found is that you can install the SSL directly to the server that's hosted at AWS. What I am confused about is how to do it. https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache.htm, among others, is a link that I have been trying to follow. I am stuck at #2 in the digicert link above becuase I can't find the SSL configuration file. Is it possible that I could not have that set up? If so, do I create the virtual host like specified in #4? Where would I place the virtual host block of code in my server? 
 
 Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: It's unclear if [ACM](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) can handle this.  Once a cert is created in ACM, the aws cli can list the CertificateChain and Certificate of your cert via `aws acm get-certificate --certificate-arn arn:aws:acm:region:account:certificate/uuid`, but where to go from there without the `CertificateKeyFile`? [Docs say it's only supported via ELB and CloudFront as of this writing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/acm/get-certificate.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as the example goes:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html2
ServerName www.yourdomain.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/your_domain_name.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/your_private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Put this inside your Apache config file using the virtual host syntax **or** as your main host depending on what you are going to do with Apache (i.e. host more sites).